# Enumerating application's process name only

Tags: winapi

How to list process names only? I looked at [Enumerating All Modules For a Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621.aspx). The example code works with process names and modules, but I want only process names.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;
    HANDLE hProcess;

    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        DWORD processID = aProcesses[i];

        cout << processID << endl;

        hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID);
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can look for a way of differentiating between the two?

Comment: The article you linked to is specifically for enumerating modules. If you don't want modules, then don't enumerate them. Look at the [Enumerating all processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623.aspx) example instead.

Comment: I googled the winapi documentation for "enumerating all processes", and immediately found the following, which appears  what appears to be what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ha. I see that Remy L. found the same thing. It's in a section called "Process Status API". Googling is good. Or in my case, DuckDuckGoing.

Comment: use for this `Process32First`/`Process32Next` or `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation`

Answer (score 0):

Get the process ids using your code and then use EnumProcessModules in combination with GetModuleBaseName to print the name of all the executables.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>

void PrintProcessName( DWORD processID )
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                   PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                   FALSE, processID );

    // Get the process name.

    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
             &cbNeeded) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                               sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }

    // Print the process name and identifier.

    _tprintf( TEXT("%s\n"), szProcessName );

    // Release the handle to the process.

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( void )
{
    // Get the list of process identifiers.

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }


    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the name and process identifier for each process.

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
        {
            PrintProcessName( aProcesses[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```